# Bash script to get total size of all s3 buckets using Cloudwatch and generate CSV report

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, report, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to generate a CSV report that contains only bucket name and total bucket size of all S3 buckets in several AWS accounts.
Don't have almost any experience with bash but I'm interested in learning. I've been looking for a script to do this and I've found one that do most of the things I need. But, script fails to give the size of almost all buckets. I'm pretty sure that the issue is at the cloudwatch parameters regarding start-time, end-time and period.
Also, I couldn't find how to put the results automatically in a CSV format such as:
**Bucketname,Totalsize**

The report needs to be done on daily basis and take an average of the actual total size for each bucket.
Thanks in advance!

This is the bash script that I've been testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
befyesterday=$(date -d @$((($(date +%s)-172800))) +%F)
yesterday=$(date -d @$((($(date +%s)-86400))) +%F)
for bucket in `aws --profile CODEV s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[*].Name' --output text`; do
sclass=$(aws --profile CODEV s3api list-objects --bucket $bucket --max-items=1 2> /dev/null | jq -r '.Contents[].StorageClass // "STANDARD"')
case $sclass in
  REDUCED_REDUNDANCY) sclass="ReducedRedundancyStorage" ;;
  GLACIER)            sclass="GlacierStorage" ;;
  DEEP_ARCHIVE)       sclass="DeepArchiveStorage" ;;
  STANDARD_IA)        sclass="StandardIAStorage" ;;
  ONEZONE_IA)         sclass="OneZoneIAStorage" ;;
  *)                  sclass="StandardStorage" ;;
esac
size=$(aws --profile CODEV cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/S3 --start-time ${befyesterday}T00:00:00 --end-time ${yesterday}T00:00:00 --period 86400 --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --dimensions Name=StorageType,Value=$sclass Name=BucketName,Value=$bucket --statistics Average --output text --query 'Datapoints[0].Average')
#printf $(echo $bucket)
#printf $(echo $sclass)
echo $bucket,$sclass,$size
done
```

The issue is that the script is showing some buckets size and others (that I know that have content and I can see the total size on Cloudwatch Dashboards) is not showing anything. Also is giving a parse error. For example:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
aaw-euwe3-d1afafr4ohioo,StandardStorage,None
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
aaw-saea1-13lgdgg91tirz,StandardStorage,None
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
aaw-usea1-100r245hza4dh,StandardStorage,14166043607.0
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I've some parse errors but in part is working and shows info, but some buckets doesn't show the size while others do. And if I check the size at AWS Cloudwatch dashboards (console) I can see that this info is not correct:
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
aaw-euwe3-d1drsafasfoo,StandardStorage,None
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
aaw-saea1-13lttbg241ff,StandardStorage,None
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 2, column 0
aaw-usea1-100radadafaza4dh,StandardStorage,14166043607.0